# Error in web.xml while creating a dynamic web project in eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I am trying to create a new web project using eclipse

File-> new -> Dynamic web project

Next Next and Finish

Here I get the web.xml and it shows me the following error

(if I select 2.5 dynamic web module version):

```
cvc-elt.1.a: Cannot find the declaration of element 'web-app'.
```

(if I select 3.0 dynamic web module version):

```
Error while downloading 'http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd' to C:
 \Users\yg178f\.lsp4xml\cache\http\java.sun.com\xml\ns\javaee\web-app_3_0.xsd.
```

Here is my web.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
    <display-name>Struts2Demo</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Hi, am getting same error.  did you find any solution to this? thanks.

Comment: I dont remember exactly, but what I can remember is, that I downloaded the XSD and kept it inside WEB-INF and rather than giving URLs, I gave the path the XSD (Though relative path) and that solved my problem at that time. 

it has been quite some time I faced this problem, so I am not sure if this was the exact solution I got at that time.

Comment: I posted the same problem here as well:

https://coderanch.com/t/736929/frameworks/error-Dynamic-web-project

Answer (score 0):

I took this `web.xml` from [here](https://www.javatpoint.com/steps-to-create-struts-2-application-example), and got rid of the issues, by removing all the URLs:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
    <web-app> 
      <filter> 
      <filter-name>struts2</filter-name> 
       <filter-class> 
        org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter 
       </filter-class> 
      </filter> 
      <filter-mapping> 
       <filter-name>struts2</filter-name> 
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern> 
      </filter-mapping> 
    </web-app>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Environment variables path image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LmMLj.png)

I had the same problem. I just uninstalled jdk along with the eclipse enterprise IDE. Downloaded jdk version 11 and installed it. Went to the environment and created a new file under JAVA_HOME and linked it to the jdk version 11. Added this to my path along with the CATALIN_HOME linked to tomcat version 9.
I then installed Eclipse enterprise ide for java developers(eclipse jee 2018-12-R) and created a new project. Voila!
The only downside is that they're a bit outdated, but hey better that than the hassle of an xml error.

Anyways if anyone's got a better solution, I am all in.